# Carrying scope of "this" into inner functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, scope

How can I extend the scope of this inward? I thought reassigning a higher scoped variable would do the trick... what am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/8bqXM/

```
function Player(configs) {

    this.opts = {
        playerID: "cSurf"
    };
    configs = $.extend(this.opts, configs);

    var the = this;

    this.init = function(){
        var $player = $("#" + the.configs.playerID);
        alert($player.attr("id"));
    }
}
var cSurf = new Player();
$(document).ready(function(){
        cSurf.init();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `configs` is not a public member of the `Player` object being created. You declared it without `var` so it's a global variable.

```
configs = $.extend(this.opts, configs);
```

should be:

```
this.configs = $.extend(this.opts, configs);
```

Then in your `init()` you can do `the.configs.playerID`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rCuXa/

*(Your jsFiddle also had MooTools loaded instead of jQuery. Check the menu on the left.)*

---

**EDIT:**

*By the way, since you're calling `init()` from the context of the new `Player` object, you really don't need to use `the` as the reference to `this`.*

Inside `init` method, `this` refers to the `Player` that was created when you call it that way.

```
var $player = $("#" + this.configs.playerID);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rCuXa/1/

---

**EDIT2:** *Additionally, if `init()` is always going to be called from the context of the `Player` instance you create, you may want to consider placing it on the `prototype` object of `Player`.*

That way it will be shared among all instances instead of being recreated for each one:

```
Player.prototype.init = function(){
               // ---------v----------"this" is the instance of Player
    var $player = $("#" + this.configs.playerID);
    alert($player.attr("id"));
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rCuXa/2/

Answer (score 0):

You just have a minor bug here. You're assigning the extend to configs, which is not on this, but then you reference it later via 'the' as if it is. This works:

```
function Player(configs) {

  this.opts = {
    playerID: "cSurf"
  };
  this.configs = $.extend(this.opts, configs);

  var the = this;

  this.init = function(){
    var $player = $("#" + the.configs.playerID);
    alert($player.attr("id"));
  }
}
var cSurf = new Player();
cSurf.init();
```